# Measure rotation around one axis with Gyroscope

Tags: math, gyroscope

[image: An image of the rotation axises of the Gyroscope of a phone]

The gyroscope of a device returns values in the following range:

```
Alpha:   0 - 360 around the Z-axis
Beta: -180 - 180 around the X-axis 
Gamma: -90 - 90  around the Y-axis
```

When I rotate the device around the Y-axis, the value 'flips' at a certain point from -90 to 90. 
I know that this is due to the fact that the gyroscope functions like a gimbal, where Alpha is the outer ring, Beta is the middle ring and Gamma is the inner ring.

My question is: how do I measure the rotation JUST around the Y-axis, without the 'flipping' effect?

Is there a mathematical way to process the alpha/beta/gamma values and get more 'useful' values for this case, so that is easier to get the amount of rotation around the X, Y or Z axis?